# write \r to outputstream

Tags: java, outputstream

The string I need to write over TCP connection has `\n` and `\r` characters. These characters are printing as `\\n` and `\\r`. How can I solve this?

```
String myLine = "this is first line\r this is second line\r third line";
outputStream.write(myLine);
```

Result:

```
this is first line\\r this is second line\\r third line
```

But I need to write result same as `myLine`(with only 1 escape sequence charecter) value.

Comment: How are you obtaining the output?  Is this what you got on the other side of the TCP connection?  I'm assuming `outputStream` is actually a `SocketOutputStream`?

Comment: the string should not be replaced with an extra escape sequence. can we do that

Comment: Why don't you convert the control characters back to the desired output after they're received?

Comment: Matt:                                                               Socket skt = new Socket(serverIP,port);
OutputStream outToServer = skt.getOutputStream();
outToServer.write(order.getBytes());

Comment: The code on the server side which you are using to rebuild the string would be useful too.  I assume it is new String(bytes[] b)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried escaping it?

```
"this is first line\\\\r this is second line\\\\r third line"
```

Comment: That would make it worse! Clearly something in the system is already doing that.